# Unity: How to programmatically find an objects mesh in the assetDatabase?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am writing a [menuitem] script to do a lot of the tedious stuff I must do when importing new models -> ready prefabs. This is tedious and repetitive work, and is perfect for scripting, except i can't figure out how. I can't get the script to find the correct mesh so that I can properly and automatically add it to the prefabs mesh collider component.

The kernal of the problem is that when the object is imported into Unity, the mesh for all my objects is simply named "default". If i where to search the assets for a mesh file with that name I would not get the right file, just some random renderer of one of my objects.

So my problem is finding a good way to address the mesh indirectly. And after extensive searching and long walks I can't think of a good solution. Manually assigning the meshes is not feasible long term due to the volume of models.

Here is a screenshot of the folder structure near the hard to get "default" mesh file structure image.

[image]

Ps: I know how to assign the mesh to my mesh collider, that is not the problem, it is being able to point unity to the right mesh to begin with.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please, show your code.

Comment: My problem was that I didn't really understand the whole load asset stuff in the asset databases, and I didn't understand enough to think of a good way to test incrementally if i had understood it...if that makes sense. As I said in my answer, I solved the problem with a workaround, but the underlying issue of addressing the mesh through the asset path is still something that is a mystery to me. And I don't like implementing solutions that work, but I don't understand in projects I do to learn. Defeats the purpose. :/

Answer (score 0):

In the end I did not solve the core of the problem, addressing the mesh through path :/ But i did find a workaround by addressing the mesh that the mesh filter have assigned to itself, as that one would generate with the correct mesh already assigned.

Edit: Here is the code i used

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;
public class MazeMenuScript : MonoBehaviour
{
// Add a menu item named "CreateMazePiece" to Maze in the menu bar.
/// <summary>
/// Turns a selected object(s) into a Prefab and ads it to the list of set `enter code here`pieces
/// </summary>
[MenuItem("Maze/CreateMazePiece")]
static void DoCreateMazePiecePrefab()
{
    Transform[] transforms = Selection.transforms;
    foreach (Transform t in transforms)
    {
        Debug.Log("Creating a prefab out of " + t.gameObject.name);
        //Add mesh collider
        MeshCollider mc = t.gameObject.AddComponent<MeshCollider>();
//this is the magic line that solved the problem:
        mc.sharedMesh = t.gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<MeshFilter>().sharedMesh;
        Debug.Log("Mesh collider with mesh added");

        Object prefab = PrefabUtility.CreateEmptyPrefab("Assets/Resources/UnsortedMazePrefabs/" + t.gameObject.name + ".prefab");
        PrefabUtility.ReplacePrefab(t.gameObject, prefab, ReplacePrefabOptions.ConnectToPrefab);
        DestroyImmediate(t.gameObject);

        AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath<GameObject>(AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath(Selection.activeObject));
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Okey, no problem :)